# read json file line by line

Tags: php, json

i want to read test.txt file line by line that i converted it to object but my problem is it just read line 1 and something is wrong because loading is little long

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__.'/test.txt','r');
while (!feof($file)){
    $file = fgets($file);
    $obj = json_decode($file);
    echo $obj->sid;
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

this my test.txt:

```
 {"sid":5555,"trans-id":"PROV_149663920543900000801","status":"0","base-price-point":"0","msisdn":"989905978846","keyword":"sub1","validity":1}
 {"sid":2244,"trans-id":"PROV_149663920543900000801","status":"0","base-price-point":"0","msisdn":"989905978846","keyword":"sub1","validity":1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting `$file` on line 3 of your code. Change it to `$line` and you are good to go.

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__.'/test.txt','r');
while (!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $obj = json_decode($line);
    echo $obj->sid;
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php

  $filename= __DIR__.'/test.txt';
  $array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filename));

  foreach ( $array as $line)
{
    $obj = json_decode($line);
    echo $obj->sid;
    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function:

```
$contents = file(__DIR__.'/test.txt');
foreach ($contents as $line)
{
    $obj = json_decode($line);
    echo $obj->sid;
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

The [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function read a file and create an array with each line of the file's contents.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest using `file` to read the file as this generates the individual lines as array entries so you can iterate though each line using a `foreach`

```
$file=__DIR__ . '/json_src.txt';
$lines=file($file);
foreach( $lines as $line ){
    $json=json_decode( $line );
    printf('%s<hr />', $json->sid );
}
```

Comment: You are not fixing what is wrong, but replace it with something else.

Comment: in what way - it works ~ failing to point out the error in the original code is that the nub of the issue with the downvote?

Comment: From the docs: [file — Reads entire file into an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)